# create XML element with "$XYZ"

Tags: java, xml, dom

I am using java to create a root element the string resolves as shown below.

```
Element root = doc.createElement("$XYZ");
```

i get and exception

```
org.w3c.dom.DOMException: INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR: An invalid or illegal XML character is specified. 
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.CoreDocumentImpl.createElement(CoreDocumentImpl.java:618)
```

any advice on how do i create the element?

Comment: You can't. `<$XYZ>` just isn't allowed.

Answer (score 6):

The '**$**' symbol is not allowed in the xml, therefore you are getting your exception.

'XYZ' would be allowed, but '$XYZ' is not allowed as it contains the '$'

You can see the [w3 spec on the starting character here](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-NameStartChar)